# ERROR: modpost: "__regmap_init" [drivers/bluetooth/btintel.ko] undefined

Tags: module, linux-kernel, bluetooth

I'm trying to build the kernel module for bluetooth driver but im stuck on the error below.

```
ERROR: modpost: "__regmap_init" [drivers/bluetooth/btintel.ko] undefined!
```

Is there any module i can build to make this symbol available ?

Build USB bluetooth driver kernel module.

This is for a NAS device, I'm using the kernel version 5.15.59

The net/bluetooth module i can compile without issues.

```
    make M=net/bluetooth
```

But drivers/bluetooth fail while building the btintel.ko module with the error above

```
make KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=net/bluetooth/Module.symvers M=drivers/bluetooth
```

Here is the .config part related to bluetooth module

```
CONFIG_BT=m
CONFIG_BT_BREDR=y
CONFIG_BT_RFCOMM=m
CONFIG_BT_RFCOMM_TTY=y
CONFIG_BT_BNEP=m
CONFIG_BT_BNEP_MC_FILTER=y
CONFIG_BT_BNEP_PROTO_FILTER=y
CONFIG_BT_HIDP=m
# CONFIG_BT_HS is not set
# CONFIG_BT_LE is not set
# CONFIG_BT_MSFTEXT is not set
# CONFIG_BT_AOSPEXT is not set
# CONFIG_BT_DEBUGFS is not set
# CONFIG_BT_SELFTEST is not set
# CONFIG_BT_FEATURE_DEBUG is not set

#
# Bluetooth device drivers
#
CONFIG_BT_INTEL=m
CONFIG_BT_RTL=m
CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB=m
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB_AUTOSUSPEND is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB_BCM is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB_MTK is not set
CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB_RTL=y
CONFIG_BT_HCIUART=m
CONFIG_BT_HCIUART_H4=y
CONFIG_BT_HCIUART_BCSP=y
CONFIG_BT_HCIUART_ATH3K=y
# CONFIG_BT_HCIUART_AG6XX is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBCM203X is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBPA10X is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBFUSB is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIDTL1 is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBT3C is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBLUECARD is not set
CONFIG_BT_HCIVHCI=m
# CONFIG_BT_MRVL is not set
# CONFIG_BT_ATH3K is not set
# end of Bluetooth device drivers
```

Comment: You need to provide (in the question post) **more details** about what you are doing. What is the kernel version? How exactly do you build the kernel module?

Comment: The function `__regmap_init` is defined in [drivers/base/regmap/regmap.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/base/regmap/regmap.c#L718) file, compilation of this file is guarded with CONFIG_REGMAP option. You may check whether this option is enabled in your configuration. According to [drivers/bluetooth/Kconfig](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.111/source/drivers/bluetooth/Kconfig), that option is automatically selected by CONFIG_BT_INTEL. But it seems something goes wrong..

Comment: CONFIG_REGMAP=y is available in the configuration after enabling CONFIG_BT_INTEL=m. But i'm trying to build the Bluetooth driver as module, i dont have the possibility to rebuild the complete kernel to have the regmap functions available in the kernel.

Comment: As example, to build the net/bluetooth module (which require some crypto function) i had to build first the crypto module and use the KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=crypto/Module.symvers during net/bluetooth module build.

Comment: So, the driver you want to build needs a function, which is not defined in the kernel. You are out of luck.

Comment: I managed to solve it. By using a patch, i was able to build regmap as module and made the required function available for bt_intel build.